# css floated element not contained within parent div

Tags: css

I am trying add responsive youtube video to my help files, but the video is not contained within the parent div and overflows it. I have tried a number of fixes suggested here but none seem to work. I am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. An example of what I am talking about can be seen here: http://designasticker.com.au/help.php You will need to use the following username and password to view the page:

Username: sticker
Password: al765bd

Comment: Nevermind, I saw the login!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this is just a floating issue. When you float elements, you take them out of the document flow--this means, the parent no longer acknowledges that the floating child exists.

You can work around this by adding an ::after pseudo-element to the parent, in this case, .displayScreen-row:

```
.displayScreen-row:after { clear: left;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: ' '; }
```

This will work in standards-compliant browsers, but not in IE 6 or 7. For those two browsers (use conditional comments to target only those,) you need to workaround like so:

IE 6:

```
.displayScreen-row { height: 100%; }
```

IE 7:

```
.displayScreen-row { min-height: 100%; }
```

IE 6 and 7 incorrectly allow a set height to acknowledge floated children.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this fix elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue in this case.

Comment: The fix is working ... your issue now is that .displayScreen-left and .displayScreen-right both have fixed heights of 100px. If you remove them, you can see the float clearing working just fine.

Comment: I'm such a hack when it comes to css, thanks for pointing that out to me. I added that with a background colour at the start so I could see the divs better. Removed the background colour but forgot about the height. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
EDIT
```

Add a negative margin:

```
margin: -120px;
```

and resize the video in the iframe:

```
<iframe width="YOUR INPUT" height="YOUR INPUT" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-JWT_tC8_iE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Replace "YOUR INPUT" with the width and height of your custom.